# How to stop table row duplications in jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, duplicates, database-connection

I am developing a jsf application with primefaces. In the application I have several tables. However whenever I refresh a page or add a new value to the table or revisit the page, the values in the table get duplicated. Now I know whats causing it. In my backing bean I use driver manager get connection in each function to establish a database connection and then I close the db connection when the function has finished. However when I refresh the page the get data function obviously gets called again and appends the values to the table. Also I know database pooling would be the best solution here but I am unable to get it to work with my application. My question is how can I prevent rows duplicating in my jsf/primefaces table and maintain a database connection so I can retrieve these values from the database? Located below is the Animal Bean class with the functions to add an animal and a function to retreive all animals from the database. **NOTE: There are no duplications in the database table, just in the jsf view or jsf table**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "animal")
@ViewScoped
public class Animal {

    public String id;
    public String breed;
    public String gender;
    public double age;
    public double weight;
    public String description;
    public String herd;
    public DataSource dataSource;
    public Connection DBConn;
    public ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    public Animal() {



    }

    public Animal(String id, String breed, double weight, double age, String gender, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of herd
     *
     * @return
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public double getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(double age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getHerd() {
        return herd;
    }

    public void setHerd(String herd) {
        this.herd = herd;
    }

    public String addAnimal() throws SQLException {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            DBConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demeter2.0", "root", "root");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Animal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Animal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        int insert = 0;

        FacesContext context;
        context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ex = context.getExternalContext();
        int value=(int)ex.getSessionMap().get("iduser");

        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        try {

            if (DBConn != null) {
                String sql = "INSERT INTO animal(animalsTag,breed,age,weight,description,gender,farmid)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                ps = (PreparedStatement) DBConn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1, id);
                ps.setString(2, breed);
                ps.setDouble(3, age);
                ps.setDouble(4,weight);
                ps.setString(5, description);
                ps.setString(6, gender);
                ps.setInt(7, value);
                insert = ps.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println(insert);
                System.out.println("Data Added Successfully");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            try {

                ps.close();
                DBConn.close();



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (insert > 0) {
            return "yes";
        } else {
            return "no";
        }

    }

    public ArrayList<Animal> allAnimals() {

         try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            DBConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demeter2.0", "root", "root");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Animal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Animal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        PreparedStatement ps = null;

         FacesContext context;
        context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ex = context.getExternalContext();
        int value=(int)ex.getSessionMap().get("iduser");

        try {

            if (DBConn != null) {
                String sql = "Select animalsTag,breed,age,weight,description,gender FROM animal where farmid = '"
                            + value + "'";
                ps = (PreparedStatement) DBConn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                if (!rs.next()) {

                    return null;
                } else {

                    rs.beforeFirst();

                    while (rs.next()) {

                        Animal animal = new Animal(
                                rs.getString("animalsTag"),
                                rs.getString("breed"),
                                rs.getDouble("age"),
                                rs.getDouble("weight"),
                                rs.getString("description"),
                                rs.getString("gender"));

                        list.add(animal);

                    }//end while

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            try {

                ps.close();
                DBConn.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return list;
    }


}
```

JSF Code

```
 <p:layout fullPage="true">

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                <div id="banner" style="float:right;">
                     <p:commandButton value="Log Out" action="#{farm.logout()}" />     
                </div>
             <p:graphicImage url="/resources/images/Demeter1.png" />
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Footer
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Left" collapsible="true">
                <p:menu>
                    <p:submenu label="Index">
                        <p:menuitem value="Manage Farm" url="managefarm.xhtml"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Add Paddock" url="outline.xhtml"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Create Grass Wedge" url="grass.xhtml"/>
                        <p:menuitem value="Herd Management" url="addAnimal.xhtml"/>

                    </p:submenu>

                </p:menu>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <h1>You can see all animals on your farm here.</h1>


                <p:dataTable var="animal" value="#{animal.allAnimals()}">
                    <p:column headerText="Id">
                        <h:outputText value="#{animal.id}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Age">
                        <h:outputText value="#{animal.age}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Breed">
                        <h:outputText value="#{animal.breed}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Weight">
                        <h:outputText value="#{animal.weight}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>



            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>
```

Comment: In dogetallanimals, does the list contains duplicates before the return  ? Would be cool if you just added the full class, without the irrelevant informations, here i don't see where the list allanimals come from. W/e just post the full class, I've an idea of what's going on but I wanna be sure.

Comment: @ Ced ok i will post the whole class, thanks for your patients! :)

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer please accept it by clicking the "v" under the score, so I know I helped you. Thank you. Also you might want to take a look at JPA, to me it's way easier to use than what you are doing with your database at the moment, just my personal opinion though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your bean is [Viewscoped](http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jsf/jsf-viewscoped-tutorial) which means that the data the bean contains is still valid when you stay on the page. Why does it matter ? Because your list of animals still contains what you added before plus what you add after in the method allAnimals(). In other words add this to the first line of your method allAnimals().

```
list = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Ahah, brilliant, thanks Ced, you are a life safer :D

Comment: @SeanSheehy Glad I helped :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set` instead of a `List`. If your worried about order you can use a `SortedSet`. A `Set` doesn't allow an object to be added to it if there is already one equal to it in the `Set`.

Comment: @ cbendar hi thanks for the reply, i forgot to mention that there are no duplication's in the database table , just in the jsf view.

Answer (score 0):

Ced's answer to setting the components to a new object worked for me. I am using MyFaces Apache Tobago as the component framework and I had to set a new UISheet() at the top of of method for retrieving the data values for the particular table. e.g. what the value attribute of the table was bound to. This is great because I don't need to worry about separating the view scope for these :-).

```
setTable(new UISheet()); //binding set to table attribute
if (data == null) {
// do something with data
} return data;
```